# Decomposition of vector space s.t. non-degenerate linear form is positive definite on a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to know is it possible that for any vector space V and any non-degenerate bilinear form on it, we can decompose $V $ as $U\oplus W$ s.t. the bilinear form is positive definite on $U$ and negative definite on $W$?

I am reading Petersen's Riemannian geometry, there is a statement for tangent space but without proof. Thanks!

Comment: In the case that $V$ is real, this follows more-or-less immediately from Sylvester's Law of Inertia, and this remains true for any ordered field.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia